# Load babel using language synonyms

Tags: babel

How can synonyms be defined to allow loading babel with, e.g., `\usepackage[nl-NL,en-GB]{babel}` rather than `\usepackage[dutch,english]{babel}`?

Comment: What do you want that for? Babel works fine as specified.

Comment: @Lusr56 I imagine it would make integration with I18N applications a little more straightforward.

Comment: @SeanAllred What we need then may be a whole rewrite of babel, renaming all internal language codes to conform to RFC-5646.

Comment: @Lusr56 I hear the maintainer accepts patches `;)`

Answer (score 3):

Just create a proxy file. For example, for Dutch the file would be `nl-NL.ldf` and its contents

```
\def\CurrentOption{dutch}
\input{dutch.ldf}
```

For `en-GB.ldf` it would be:

```
\def\CurrentOption{british}
\input{english.ldf}
```

But the language names, as set in `\selectlanguage` and the like, are still `dutch` and `british`, respectively.

Comment: So, again, what's the gain?

Comment: @Lusr56 I've edited the answer to show this case.

Comment: I removed my objection and edited the answer to make it complete and explicit.